# Validity of using linear regression to establish relationship in a multiple variable setting

Tags: least-squares

My question is very fundamental and maybe naive to some, but it has been bothering me and no one can seem to answer it reasonably!

Lot of papers in economics empirically establish relationship (not necessarily causal) between two variables say $Y$ and $X$ by modelling them as a linear regression. But say the true model of nature is actually 
$ y = \alpha + \beta x_{1}x_{2} +\gamma x_{3} + \epsilon$
where $\epsilon$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and a finite variance. (I do not know this nature's model but can only guess which variables go into the model)

Say as a researcher I have the fortunate intuition that $x_{1}, x_{2},x_{3}$ all affect $y$. I run a OLS model of $y$ against $x_{1}, x_{2},x_{3}$. Should I expect to find a statistically significant coefficient for $x_{1}$?

After all, when I use OLS I am assuming the true model is $ y = \alpha +\beta_{1}x_{1}+\beta_{2}x_{2}+\beta_{3}x_{3}+\epsilon$

Also since the model is multivariate, it is not like I can use layman justification by simply plotting the graphs.

Answer (score 0):

If you misspecify the model, you may get all kinds of answers. But you are not helpless. You can visualize the data, you can run some exploratory tests. More importantly, you can use *kernel smoothers* to get a preliminary estimate of the $Y = f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ surface. That will give you an idea which model to specify. That will allow you to avoid blunders like $y=α+β_1 x_1 + β_2 x_2+β_3 x_3 + ϵ$.